# How to implement dynamic properties in Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to be able to back a dynamic property with a Map using a lookup in noSuchMethod(). However the latest changes makes the incoming property reference name unavailable. I can understand the minification scenario requiring us to use Symbols rather than Strings for names, but this makes implementing serializable dynamic properties difficult. Anyone have good ideas on how to approach this problem?

- I can't use String names since the String names are not fixed between calls to the minifier. (This would completely break serialization)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the original name with [`MirrorSystem.getName(symbol)`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorSystem.html#getName)

So a dynamic class could look like :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {
  final _properties = new Map<String, Object>();

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    if (invocation.isAccessor) {
      final realName = MirrorSystem.getName(invocation.memberName);
      if (invocation.isSetter) {
        // for setter realname looks like "prop=" so we remove the "="
        final name = realName.substring(0, realName.length - 1);
        _properties[name] = invocation.positionalArguments.first;
        return;
      } else {
        return _properties[realName];
      }
    }
    return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
  }
}

main() {
  final a = new A();
  a.i = 151;
  print(a.i); // print 151
  a.someMethod(); // throws
}
```

Comment: is the real name format something that is fairly stable or do I have to worry about updating my code everytime a new version of dart comes out?

Comment: I don't really know if the format is specified but in the [language specification](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html) there are references to _setter `v=`_. So I would say it's almost defined. Feel free to ask on the mailing list or in an other SO question :)

Comment: This pieces of code did not runable. I got `The setter 'i' isn't defined for the class 'A'.` error.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:json' as json;

main() {
    var t = new Thingy();
    print(t.bob());
    print(t.jim());
    print(json.stringify(t));
}

class Thingy {
    Thingy() {
        _map[const Symbol('bob')] = "blah";
        _map[const Symbol('jim')] = "oi";
    }

    final Map<Symbol, String> _map = new Map<Symbol, String>();

    noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
        return _map[invocation.memberName];
    }

    toJson() => {
        'bob': _map[const Symbol('bob')],
        'jim': _map[const Symbol('jim')]};
}
```

**Update - dynamic example:**

```dart
import 'dart:json' as json;

main() {
    var t = new Thingy();
    t.add('bob', 'blah');
    t.add('jim', 42);
    print(t.bob());
    print(t.jim());
    print(json.stringify(t));
}

class Thingy {
    final Map<Symbol, String> _keys = new Map<Symbol, String>();
    final Map<Symbol, dynamic> _values = new Map<Symbol, dynamic>();

    add(String key, dynamic value) {
        _keys[new Symbol(key)] = key;
        _values[new Symbol(key)] = value;
    }

    noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
        return _values[invocation.memberName];
    }

    toJson() {
        var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        _keys.forEach((symbol, name) => map[name] = _values[symbol]);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: what I really want is something like an Expando object. I want to be able to define Thingy with fixed properties + additional properties that can be added at runtime.

Comment: I've added an dynamic example - is that what you mean? The advantage of this is that you don't have to use reflection, which means it will work better with dart2js. It should be pretty easy to handle setters too instead of using add - you can use some of the code in Alexadres's example above.

Comment: Oops - you obviously can't handle setters without mirror.GetName().

Comment: @GregLowe How to suppress "method not found" errors such as [these](https://pasteboard.co/JqrfaNB.png)?

Comment: Ah: meanwhile, it has become [forbidden](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/442) in Dart to invoke methods on objects that are not specifically declared.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the solution of @Alexandre Ardhuin, I made some modification to make it runnable.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class object {
  final _properties = new Map<String, Object>();

  object();

  object.from(Map<String, Object> initial) {
    initial.entries.forEach((element) => _properties[element.key] = element.value);
  }

  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    if (invocation.isAccessor) {
      final realName = MirrorSystem.getName(invocation.memberName);
      if (invocation.isSetter) {
        // for setter realname looks like "prop=" so we remove the "="
        final name = realName.substring(0, realName.length - 1);
        _properties[name] = invocation.positionalArguments.first;
        return;
      } else {
        return _properties[realName];
      }
    }
    return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return _properties.toString();
  }
}

main() {
  // we can't use var or object type here, because analysis will consider
  // https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#undefined_setter
  // The setter 'i' isn't defined for the type 'object'
  // So dynamic is required here!
  dynamic a = object.from({'a': 123, 'b': 234});
  a.i = 151;
  print(a); // print {a: 123, b: 234, i: 151}
  try {
    a.someMethod(); // throws NoSuchMethodError
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need "dynamic properties", it should be enough to use Symbols as keys in the Map. If you also want to serialize that map, then you need to keep track of the original String names and use those for serialization. When deserializing, you'd have to create new Symbols from those Strings.

Note that all these scenarios (and basically everything that involves `new Symbol`) require a compiler to create a mapping of original names to the minified ones and put this mapping into the program, which of course makes it bigger.

Comment: yeah the problem is how do I get access to the original String names? noSuchMethod doesn't expose the original String, all you get from the Invocation object is the Symbol.

Comment: Well, you have to record the original names when you are putting things into the map. Edit: oh yeah, the accepted answer is right, there is a backwards mapping. Didn't remember about that.